# TS: Better alternative to Partial - Partial is not type safe

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Just discovered partial can be pretty wild, I wasn't expecting this kind of behavior. It seems like `Partial` is not type safe?

What other alternative exists?

```
type A = {
    a: string;
    b: string;
}

type B = Partial<A>

type C = {
    a: string;
    d: string;
}

let b: B = { b: 'b'};


const c: C = {
    d: 'd',
    a: 'a',
    ...b, // no error ... what??
}

const cc: C = {
    d: 'd',
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b' // error
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5gNxoYBGuBJF1AviiqJFAEIJQAKmQsGKYANgB4YAPnadoAYT6oMWBkTJUa6ACbqmWtijERgUer0RJzuAOS1bLaigDGAe1IEoL3EqvaoPShbHVsAGgCcYMxwgIA6BNoIliA

Comment: Nothing to do with `Partial` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwlC8UDeAoK6oEMBcUDOwATgJYB2A5mhgCa4EkUoC+KKAxgPakFRu5yJUGLLgDkmUQBoq6WlFHUpMqADo1ACiRQARmO2ioTAJSSoAejNRSHKBEKEOhZkA. Excess property checking is a more complex topic than you might think

Comment: @AlexWayne super interesting.
Any hint on how to safely mass assign safely then?

Comment: ok
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727

seems like a long date topic.

Thanks for the hint

Comment: First, ask yourself if you're sure this is a problem. Types are contracts. If an object can fulfills that contract, then it's considered fine. That value may have more than that, but that's not a problem. Even the case it does error is only a problem because you'd lose the ability to access `b` since it's not part of the type, which means it's most likely a mistake. But it's presence does not make your code unsound.